# elastic-builder: how to retrieve all unique value of one specific field

Tags: javascript, typescript, elasticsearch

I am completely new using elastic search with current project(elastic-builder is used) and documentation of elastic-builder is bit confusing.
I need to retrieve all unique values of one specific field, say `creator` of tasks stored on server, how should I compose the query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to get all the unique values sorted by count from a field. If you use the default mapping for your index, your `creator` field should have a subfield `creator.keyword` that you can use for the terms aggregation.